# initialization of class member variables in base and derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say we have a `Base` class and a `Derived` class:

```
class Base {

  public:

    Base(int x) : var1(x)

    int process(){
       //return some function of var1
    }

  protected:
    int var1;

}

class Derived : public Base {

  Derived(int init) : Base(init), a(process()), b(process()) {}

  protected:

    int a;
    int b;


}
```

In other words, when we initialize `Derived`, we assume that the `Base` constructor is called first, which initializes the `var1` member variable in the base class with the `init` value, and then the `a` and `b` member variables are initialized using the `process()` function, which depends on the value set to `var1`.

Notice that for this code to be correct we need to make sure that `Base(init)` is called before `a(process())` and `b(process())`.

Is it valid to assume in C++ that the above initialization order will be maintained? Or do I need to change the `Derived` constructor to the following to guarantee the order of initialization?

```
Derived(int init) : Base(init) {

  a = process();
  b = process();
}
```

Comment: No you don't need to do anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

The order is guaranteed, you do not have to do anything. Bases are initialized before members (in the order in which they were declared). Members are initialized in the order in which they were declared [[class.base.init]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#13) (note: order of declaration, *not* the order in which the *mem-initializers* appear in the constructor's initializer list!).

You can also rely on bases and members being destroyed in the exactly opposite order of the order in which they were initialized…